# Find the orthogonal contrasts of the sources of variations in the following design

Tags: anova

[image]

I know the condition of what an orthogonal contrast is: the dot product of their coefficients should be zero. Plus if we are given a set of contrasts, they are supposed to be mutually orthogonal to one another.

This is the solution to the question but I can't seem to understand why:

[image]

All I have as an explanation is this:

[image]

I can see that the degrees of freedom add up to 5 which is one less than 6, the number of variables.
But I still don't get how we derived the expressions.

I can see that those expressions satisfy those conditions. But I can't understand how we derived it.

> 1) The sum of the coefficients in each linear contrast
>   must sum to zero, and
>
> 2) The sum of the products of the corresponding
>   coefficients in any two contrasts must equal zero

Comment: I've asked the question and no one has replied for days.

Comment: If you type out the relevant parts of the post instead of using pictures, maybe then it will generate better response.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/441558/find-the-orthogonal-contrasts-of-the-sources-of-variations-in-the-following-desi